# Typescript: Iterate through a dropdown

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript and I have a dropdown whose values I need to iterate through.
This is the code I am trying:

```
var sortBy = document.getElementById("SortbySel");
```

I want to iterate through the options but since this is an HTMLElement, I am unable to do so.
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to fetch dropdown items from html? Isn't it better to have it defined in ts class and passed to drop down as options?

Comment: Look here for how to do it in javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript If typescript is confused about the structure / available functions of an object you can hack through it with `(foo as any).secretFunction()`.  Better to find the .d.ts files and fix the source of the problem, sometimes that's too much trouble for a small thing

Comment: To add the values to a custom styled dropdown control. I needed to iiterate through the select element and add them to the custom control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the `querySelectorAll` function:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#SortbySel option');
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    console.log(options.item(i).value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-select-iteration) stackblitz POC where I iterated over `select HTML element`

If you are using `typescript` it is always better to use specific classes like `HTMLSelectElement` & `HTMLOptionElement` instead of using conventional `var` declarations as it helps a lot in intellisense.

the code looks like this -

```
let selectElement: HTMLSelectElement = 
document.getElementById('select') as HTMLSelectElement;

for (let i = 0; i < selectElement.options.length; i++) {
  let option: HTMLOptionElement = selectElement.options[i];
  console.log(option);
}
```